# How can I make a port inside a virtual machine accessible to the host if the virtual interface has its traffic forwarded through a TPROXY target?

Tags: networking, iptables, port, ip-address

I have a virtual machine connected to virtual interface that has all its traffic sent through a TPROXY transparent proxy:

```
ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
ip link set tap0 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tap0
ip rule add fwmark 1088 table 100

ip rule add fwmark 1088 table 100
ip route add local default dev tap0 table 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i tap0 -p tcp \
  -j TPROXY -s 10.0.0.2 --on-ip 10.0.0.1 \
  --on-port 10000 --tproxy-mark 1088
```

The virtual interface in host side has the IP address 10.0.0.1 and the virtual machine 10.0.0.2. But I cannot access any TCP port from host side on the address of the virtual machine (for example 10.0.0.2:8080) because the iptables TPROXY rule blocks all connections coming to the virtual machine address.

How can I make ports in the virtual machine IP be accessible in the host side?

Comment: What's the reason for the TPROXY configuration? What about adding a second interface to your virtual machine (on a different virtual network) that you use for direct access?

Comment: @larsks I need to forward the traffic comming from tap0 to Tor. I know that Tor has the REDIRECT port but I prefer TPROXY because it "locks" all the TCP traffic in the virtual interface, it seems more secure. Adding a secondary interface is a good idea, or maybe, a secondary gateway in the same interface.

Comment: The correct way to have tproxy work is documented there: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.rst the route using `dev lo` isn't a setting you can change as you wish. Note the use of the socket match etc.

Comment: @A.B In my case I can select a different interface apart from loopback if I wanna make the connections come from a subnet and be redirected to TPROXY. The only limitation is that TPROXY require a listening port on the local network, not external addresses.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: @A.B It's alright.